# Discrepancy between shared memory from /proc/meminfo and ipcs

Tags: linux, memory, performance, shared-memory

Running `free -hm` outputs:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           15G        15G       389M       321M       169M        11G
-/+ buffers/cache:       3.9G        11G
Swap:         7.9G        80K       7.9G
```

The 'shared' column is the same as /proc/meminfo Shmem (332072 kb), but when I try to track down the processes that are using the shared memory with `ipcs -m`, it only shows ~24MB usage:

```
------ Shared Memory Segments --------
key        shmid      owner      perms      bytes      nattch     status      
0x00000000 851968     dangets    700        7978224    2          dest         
0x00000000 458753     dangets    700        7978224    2          dest         
0x00000000 589827     dangets    700        7978224    2          dest         
0x0052e2c1 327684     postgres   600        48         5
```

Here's where I get fuzzier, so please correct me if I'm wrong.

I also looked for any `tmpfs` mounts, and it is only the `/run` mount, which `du -chs /run` says that it only is 123MB.

Can someone please explain or point me to documentation on what actually contributes to the `/proc/meminfo` Shmem field?  Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at https://lists.kernelnewbies.org/pipermail/kernelnewbies/2013-July/008628.html

Comment: Deleted files still kept open in `tmpfs` count as shared. For additional ideas, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/666762/20336